# Cookie not being stored or used

Tags: cookies

I'm setting a cookie in a response from my web service. The `set-cookie` header is coming through, and I can see the cookie in the network tab in Chrome, but the cookie isn't being stored. It doesn't show up in the resources->cookies tab, and the cookie isn't sent with subsequent requests. Nothing shows up in the JS console. I've also tried leaving the domain field off the cookie, but it still isn't stored.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Is there a way to debug the browser to understand why the cookie was rejected from being stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it had to do with the way I was making the request. I expected `fetch()` to work the same way as XHR requests. Setting `credentials: 'include'` on my `fetch` call resolved the problem. See [5.6.14 of the fetch spec](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#http-network-fetch)